# Let $a, b\in L\supset K$ be transcendental over $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that $b$ is algebraic over $K(a)$, the subfield of $L$ generated by $K$ and $a$, if and only if $a$ is algebraic over $K(b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Both statements say that there is a 2 variable polynomial $f\in K[x,y]$ such that $f(a,b)=0$.